# How to get the list of items that are extra in one ArrayList when compared to another?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two ArrayList with the following items

```
ArrayList1    {"bc.jpg","12.jpg","xy.png","123.gif","ref.gif","gef.png","abc.jpg"}

ArrayList2   {"tt.jpg","12.jpg","xy.png","gef.png","abc.jpg"}
```

**The items in the list may not be sorted**

Is there a function to find out the extra items in ArrayList1 ("bc.jpg","123.gif","ref.gif") which are not present in ArrayList2?

Comment: SO community is better than Google search ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set<String> copy = new HashSet<String>(list1);
copy.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println(copy);
```

If you need to preserve the order and cardinality of the duplicates, you can use List/ArrayList instead of Set/HashSet but it will be less efficient.

Comment: The copy doesn't need to be a Set -- removeAll is in Collection -- but it makes sense if the list might be long.

Comment: thanks it worked.. But I have used ArrayList instead of HashSet to avoid casting.. marking as right..